# Python Flushing and Already Closed File

Tags: python

How do I add a check to avoid flushing a file f with f.flush() when some function has already done f.close()?

I can't seem to figure out how to do so :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [try ...except](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for this purpose i guess

> Any operation which requires that the file be open will raise a
>   ValueError after the file has been closed

OR use fileobj.closed property and if it True then don't do flush

> file.closed bool indicating the current state of the file object. This
>   is a read-only attribute; the close() method changes the value. It may
>   not be available on all file-like objects.

Answer (score 3):

Just examine `closed` attribute of file object.